# How to display image with HTTP header in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a basic HTML page with one button. On click of that button it should invoke an HTTP URL(with Accept header) on GET request.

The output of HTTP URL is a image or audio or video(as per the request header).
How should I write a Javascript or Ajax call

```
<html>

<form>

<input type="submit" id='img_display' onClick=imgDisp()>
<div id='display'></div>

</form>

</html>
```

Ajax code-

```
$("#img_display").on( "click", function imgDisp() {
 $.ajax(            
    {
        type: 'GET',                
        url: 'http_url',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend : function(xhr)
         {  
             xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'image/png');
        },              
        success: function(data){
                alert("successfully")                                            
        },
        error: function(e){     
              alert("error post" + e);
        }               
    }
    );
```

});

Comment: sidenote: having both a javascript click event and onClick will cause it to fire twice, or console error that function imgDisp not defined

Answer (score 1):

To make an Ajax request that returns either an image, audio, or video content, and forcing the receiving Javascript to guess the content type of a potentially huge blob of data, is  poor design.

Depending on what type the audio and video content is, it may not be possible at all to do things that way.

It's *much* better to make one Ajax request that, say, returns a JSON object with the content type and URL:

```
{ "type": "image",
  "url": "http://example.com/images/5/example.jpg" }
```

or, for a video:

```
{ "type": "video",
  "url": "http://example.com/videos/5/example.mp4" }
```

You get the drift.

You can then handle the content appropriately, for example create an `img` element and set the `src` property to the URL, or invoke a video or audio player with the video URL.

This way, you can also send along other metadata that is relevant to rendering the end result - image dimensions and alt text, for example.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you!!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Submit").click(function(){
        var image_url = $(".imageurl").val();
        $(".ImageContainer").html("<img src='"+image_url+"' width='200'>");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="imageurl">
<button id="Submit">Submit</button>
<div class="ImageContainer">
    <!--Image Display -->    
</div>
```